# validate using jquery when having multiple rows

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a page created by Vapor, rendered in .leaf. using bootstrap.

The page has a form, that form consist of rows, each row contains 5 input fields :

1. plan yes/no -> checkbox
2. deadline -> date
3. collaborator
4. description
5. Time

5

```
 <form>
                #loop(line_items, "line_item") {
                <div class="form-group row" id=#(line_item.id)>
                    <div class="col col-sm-1">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control form-control-sm checkbox" name="plan">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-2">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="deadline">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-2">
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" >
                        <option id=0>Not assigned</option>

                            #loop(users,"user") {
                                <option id=#(user.id)>#(user.name)</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-1">
                    <input type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" value=#(line_item.line_item/amount)>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-3">
                    #(line_item.description)
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button">Create Tasks</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

I would like to validate :

- deadline : required IF checkbox plan yes/no is set, otherwise it's not required
- currently only the first row is validated, if there are more rows they don't get validated. How should I do that ?

I'm using :

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>
```

and in that validation.js I'm going to write the requirements (I played around a bit with them and it was great except for the 2 problems here above)

In response to Tyan Tuosto: no real code just played around:

```
$(function() {

    $("#task-form").validate({

        rules : {
            deadline: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you have already to do the validation?

Comment: edited post with example

Comment: Your validation is targeting a `form` with the `id` of `task-form`, but there is no such thing in the HTML markup you're showing us.  Also, please show the  HTML markup as rendered in the browser, instead of your Vapor code.